# Function calling Two times when using for in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code executing two times when click radio name not radio button , how to stop that code executing two times.If i remove `for` it will work as usual

### HTML

```
<li class="test">
    <input type="radio" id="check" class="rd" name="v" value="1" />
    <label for="check">Radio 1</label>
</li>
```

### JS

```
$(".test").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(1);
});
```

**[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nh23cqbo/21/)**

Comment: When the radio button is clicked, the click bubbles up to the container and triggers another click, so you see it 2 times. Depending on your use, you probably don't need to bind to the container but bind to the radio button instead, perhaps on change

Comment: `label for="id"` has an internal browser mechanism of clicking the radio button. That causes it executing twice.

Comment: So clicking on LI should check radio button or not? What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Any angry da..? Just now came into the office da.. I hope you understand me.. :(

Comment: @Bala Yeah.. I'll.. do it post lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these:

```
$(".test").click(function (event) {
    alert(1); 
    return false; //stops it from being handled a 2nd time
});
```

or

```
$(".test input:radio").click(function (event) { //so you only bind to click on the radio button
    alert(1);
});
```

And another option is to use `change` instead of `click`:

```
$(".test").change(function (event) {
    alert(1);  
});
```

To confirm zvona's comment try:

```
$(".test").click(function (event) {
    alert(1 + event.target);
});
```

It'll be fired twice, one for `[object HTMLLabelElement]` and one for `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Update: A. Wollf is right, `return false;` stops radio button being checked.

Comment: But `return false;` prevent default behaviour of clicking on radio label. +1 for the second one ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

The radio button trigger the click on the li.

You can trigger the event on the radio button directly.

```
$("#check").click(function (event) {

    alert(1);
});
```

Or you can check if the event target is the li.

```
$(".test").click(function (event) {
    // i don't know exactly what the condition will be. Inspect the event.target to look at the property you want.
    if (event.target.html == "li")
    {
        alert(1);

    }
});
```

Comment: Should be e.g: `if ($(event.target).is(':radio'))`  http://jsfiddle.net/nh23cqbo/23/  Just seeing, maybe OP's wants entire LI to be clickable, so forget my comment

Comment: It would be easy to find with firebug but i don't have firefox install at work

Comment: @MathieuLabrieParent Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you have firefox at work? Some policy?

Comment: Yeah, i'm working at the goverment and i'm not admin of the machine ... we have to conform to what they use. We have IE9, i can't even test css3 and html5 in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="test">
    <input type="radio" id="check" class="rd" name="v" value="1" />
    <label for="check">Radio 1</label>
</li>
```

JS

```
$("#check").click(function (event) { // You could change this to $(".rd") if you need to reuse it for other radio buttons
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(1);
});
```

Also, there is no reason to use a radio button if you only have one available option.  Use a checkbox, instead!